# Show that $f_n(x)=x^n(1−x^n)$ is not monotone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)$

$A = [0,1]$

I showed that convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $0$ is not uniform,there is another question why here Dini's theorem can't be applied.All criterions are fulfilled except that $f_n(x)$ is not monotone.

Is there a  way to prove that $f_n(x)$ is not monotone?

We should consider $\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}=\frac{x(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x^n}$ stuck here.

Comment: @MartinR I know that but it is not monotone either.I am interested finding straight way proving that it's not monotone

Comment: It should be $\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}=\frac{x(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x^n}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MartinR Yes thank you

Comment: For each $n$, $f_n(x)$ is monotone function. Presumably you mean that the _convergence_ is not monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f_n(x) \le 1/4$, with equality exactly if $x^n = 1/2$, that is for $x = x_n = 1/\sqrt[n]2$. Therefore
$$
 f_n(x_n) = \frac 14 > f_{n+1}(x_n) \, ,
$$
which shows that $(f_n)$ is not increasing, and
$$
 f_n(x_{n+1}) < \frac 14 = f_{n+1}(x_{n+1}) \, ,
$$
which shows that $(f_n)$ is not decreasing.

Here is a plot of $f_2, f_3, f_4$ (created with wxMaxima). One sees that all $f_n$ have the same maximum, but attain the maximum at different points. Therefore the sequence $(f_n)$ cannot be monotone.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for stupid question can you explain how you got that $f_n(x) \le 1/4$?

Comment: $y(1-y) \le \left( \frac{y + (1-y)}{2}\right)^2 = \frac 1 4$ from the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean, or simply by looking at the vertex of the parabola $y \mapsto y(1-y)$.

Comment: Can you please explain why from first two inequalities follows that it't not monotone?I am new to functional sequences therefore it's still not easy with indexing.

Comment: @unit1991: The first inequality shows that $(f_n)$ is not increasing, and the second inequality shows that $(f_n)$ is not decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for answer is it possible to answer this using derivatives?

Comment: @unit1991: Dini's theorem requires that $(f_n)$ is a monotone sequence. That means that either $f_{n+1}(x) \le f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$, or $f_{n+1}(x) \ge f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$. That has nothing to do with $f_n(x)$ being a monotone function of $x$, so derivatives $f_n'(x)$ do not really help.